# SSO update using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-sign-on

I've got an issue with one client, who has using `SSO` and `session` is set to 20 mins. The problem is we are using `VUEJS` for front end and sometimes, they are writing one single page without interaction to backed more than 20 mins and they lose their unsaved text. I was asked to repair it, so basically when `session` is going to end, it will help them not to lose all data, for example, it will ask them to login again and then allow them to continue in their text. I did some investigation and basically I am thinking, that maybe I can do some javascript, which will be running on the background, and if it is going to be close to `session` end, it will display some popup to ask them "Do you want to continue? ..." **Yes/No**, and basically, if they click yes it will call backend API and this would update session.

My question is, is it the right approach on how to do it? Does exist any standard solution for it? Is there any other solution?

Thanks for all the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, with SSO, there is a refresh token you can use to refresh the authorization token of the user without them knowing. This allows you to extends the user's session untils de refresh token expires, usually much much after the authorization token.  You can look your SSO documents to try and find how to implements it. 
In most cases, you would use an interceptor to check, before each request, if the authorization token is still active, and if not, refresh it using the refresh token. 

Now, i'm not sure how `VueJs` works with interceptor but i'm sure it's possible.

Comment: interceptors in vue work just like you described, you can set it to every request and do whatever you want in there, you have interceptors for requests and for responses. Basically works like you imagine it would

Comment: Thank you for answers. I'll need to learn more, could you please give my link to some article/guide etc. where I can read little bit more about it ?

Comment: You can read [this article](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/) about refresh token on oauth, it should gives you a good idea on what to do.